# Textarea doesn't get updated when I click generate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-build

Trying to use a custom build example to generate and load code pages only when the user clicks on check boxes and submits. However the textarea does not seem to update at all.

I am attempting to get my code working like this example 
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/customDownload.html

Here is the code.

```
             <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/docs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Enter Project Name Here</a>

          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="documentation.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="customDownload.html" class="active">Custom Download</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container">

<header class="jumbotron subhead" id="overview">
  <h1>Customize and download</h1>
  <p class="lead"><a href="#">Download the full repository</a> or customize your entire <em>Enter Project Name Here</em> build by selecting only the components that you need.</p>
  <div class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><a href="#css-downloads">1. Choose and Generate CSS components</a></li>
      <li><a href="#javascript-downloads">2. Choose and Generate JavaScript components</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3. Be Happy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<hr>
<p class="well note">
<strong>Note:</strong> This example page uses the jQuery plugin, <a href="https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js" target="_blank">SelectBoxIt</a>, to demonstrate how to create custom builds with Downloadbuilder.js.
</p>

<section class="custom-downloads" id="css-downloads">
  <div class="page-header">
    <a class="btn btn-small pull-right toggle-all" href="#">Toggle all</a>
    <h1>
      1. Choose and Download CSS components
      <small>Get just the CSS you need</small>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      <label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.css"> SelectBoxIt CSS</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <a class="btn" data-bind="css-downloads" id="css-generate">Generate CSS</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary download-button" id="css-download" download="jquery.selectboxit.css">Download CSS</a>
  <br /><br />
  <textarea class="source-area default sourceView" id="generated-css-source">// Minified source</textarea>
</section>

<section class="custom-downloads" id="javascript-downloads">
  <div class="page-header">
    <a class="btn btn-small pull-right toggle-all" href="#">Toggle all</a>
    <h1>
      2. Choose and Download JavaScript components
      <small>Get just the JavaScript you need</small>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      <label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.core.min.js" disabled> SelectBoxIt Core</label>
      <label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.ariaAccessibility.min.js"> Aria Accessibility</label>
      <label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.destroy.min.js"> Destroy method</label>
      <label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.disable.min.js"> Disable method</label>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /row -->
  <br />
  <a class="btn" href="#" data-bind="javascript-downloads" id="javascript-generate">Generate JavaScript</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary download-button" id="javascript-download" download="jquery.selectboxit.js">Download JavaScript</a>
  <br /><br />
  <textarea class="source-area default sourceView" id="generated-javascript-source">// Minified source</textarea>
</section>
</div>

    </div><!--/.fluid-container-->
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Downloads</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <a class="btn btn-large" href="#" target="_blank" data-lang="css" download="jquery.selectboxit.css">Download CSS</a>
            <a class="btn btn-large" href="#" target="_blank" data-lang="javascript">Download JavaScript</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tocify.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/base64.js"></script>
    <script src="js/javascripts/DownloadBuilder.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() {

            $("a[href='#']").click(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();

            });

            $(".toggle-all").on("click", function() {

                $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(":disabled").each(function() {

                    $(this).attr("checked", !$(this).attr("checked"));

                });

            });

            var builder = new DownloadBuilder();

            $("#css-generate").on("click", function() {

                builder.buildURL($("#css-downloads input[type='checkbox']:checked"), "jquery.selectboxit.css", "css", function(data) {

                    $("#generated-css-source").text(data.content);

                    if(!data.content) {

                        $("#css-download").fadeOut("slow");

                    }

                    if(data.url) {

                        $("#css-download").attr("href", data.url).fadeIn("slow");

                    }

                });

            });

            $("#javascript-generate").on("click", function() {

                builder.buildURL($("#javascript-downloads input[type='checkbox']:checked"), "jquery.selectboxit.js", "javascript", function(data) {

                    $("#generated-javascript-source").text(data.content);

                    if(!data.content) {

                        $("#javascript-download").fadeOut("slow");

                    }

                    if(data.url) {

                        $("#javascript-download").attr("href", data.url).fadeIn("slow");

                    }

                });

            });

        });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you use textarea use .val() not .text() .. .val(data.content); I dont know what's data.content if you check it  just use .val()

Comment: I've tried this but still the text area is not updating correctly

Comment: you use data.content and data.url  and I'm not find var data .. try to console.log(data.content); to see what is that .. or just tell me  what data suppose to be?

Comment: data is supposed to be different js files appearing in the textarea

Comment: Ok start from data .. check from where you get data .. and use console.log(data); after each step to know what the data is .. Good Luck

Comment: @lollipopwizardkid create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: @Aminul http://jsfiddle.net/lollipopwizardkid/ujp0b1uw/

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$("#generated-javascript-source").val(data.content);` 
instead of

```
 $("#generated-javascript-source").text(data.content);
```

replace all `.text(data.content); with .val(data.content);;`

Comment: I tried this but I'm still having the same problem. The textarea is not updating.